# Holding a select row into a variable and accessing its fields with informix

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

Is there a way in Informix to create a ROW type named or unnamed that you can put a row resulted from a select into? I'm working in a stored procedure.

What I want is something like this:

```
DEFINE ROW rowVar;

SELECT * INTO rowVar FROM myTableName;
```

Haven't been able to find the correct syntax so far. I want the row object to behave sort-of like it would be SAMEAS with the table columns.

Comment: My immediate reaction is 'No'.  A brief pause for a second thought suggests 'if you changed the `*` appropriately, you might be able to do it'.  But that probably wasn't what you had in mind, and I'd need to think about how to actually do it — I suspect you'd be required to list the names that the `*` expands to, for example.

Comment: SELECT INTO can only be used for storing a result set in a temporary table. A row can only exist inside a table, not by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I do this regularly with Informix.

```
define o_Row row(cs_nr int not null, addr_nr int, last_name varchar(255));

foreach
  select cs into o_Row from cs where cs_nr = 1234
end foreach;
```

if you are returning more than one row or are not in a foreach you can use a multiset.

```
define o_Row multiset(row(cs_nr int not null, addr_nr int, last_name varchar(255))not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use an "undefined" `ROW`type in Informix Stored Procedure Language (SPL).
If you try the following (using Informix 12.10.FC8DE):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_dummy();
DEFINE generic_row ROW;
END PROCEDURE;
```

It returns the following error:

```
-999    Not implemented yet.
```

The [Informix manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1318.htm) does not seem to be correct:

> The following statements show examples of generic ROW variables and
>   named ROW variables:
>
> DEFINE d ROW;               -- generic ROW variable

If you define the fields of the `ROW` then you can use it inside the SPL.